# Is there a way to load partial views from server side when using angular?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug, partials

I am working on a single page web application and have run into a question for which I cannot seem to find the answer. 
Is there a way to load partial views from server side when using angular? I am using nodeJs, with express and Jade, and wanted to load partial views into angular, but I am confused on how I would do such. Is there any particular guideline that I should follow to structure my files?

I do not want to load all of my partials from angular, so I wanted to know if there is a way to load the views in from node.

EDIT: What I mean to ask is, am I allowed to load in partial jade views on angular? Does that have any effect on the way the page renders?

Comment: You can just use the jade templating, and make the things that you would have filling in your `ng-view` instead extend a jade template. Also, is it clear to you what is executing on the client and what is on the server? Your question is still very vague to me

Comment: Are you asking if you can get a `express partial view` and load it into angular? I don't think so. You can have `express views` in jade and can load angular in it, but angular partials need to be html and available in the `public directory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Angular is a Single Page Application framework, it means that you application (ie HTML+CSS+JS) is loaded once at first load in the browser, and all what happens is a communication of raw data (JSON over REST for example), Angular is in charge of displaying correctly the already-loaded-html correctly according to these raw data.